# MySQL insert statement fails with foreign key constraint

Tags: php, mysql

I have this statement:

```
INSERT INTO `alias`( `alias`, `ref_links_id`) VALUES ("3334",4)
```

And I get this error:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 

(`bestr_main`.`alias`, CONSTRAINT `alias_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ref_links_id`) 

REFERENCES `links` (`link_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

The alias table is connected to link table with a foreign key.
Why do I get this error when inserting a record?

I see now.. I tried to change the link between the keys to another table and I get this:

```
  1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 

  (`bestr_main`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-73c_38e0'>, CONSTRAINT 

 `#sql-73c_38e0_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ref_links_id`) REFERENCES `refs` (`ref_id`) 

 ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE C)
```

What does that say?

Comment: Error itself tells the reason

Comment: Please, add which foriegn key is avialable in primary key table, Otherwise remove foriegn key from table...

Comment: Please start inserting values from the parent table which has referred , because of the parent table  does'nt exist with the values it may  results with above mentioned errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the error

```
FOREIGN KEY (ref_links_id) REFERENCES links (link_id))
```

Means

```
`links`.link_id  (Parent)

`alias`.ref_links_id (Child)
```

and  no child exist without parent. so first check parent table for the value which you are inserting into child table

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a link_id with value 4 in your `links` table, if you wanna insert a 4 in `alias.ref_links_id`.

Create it in the `links` table first if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

the link table doesn't have the value '4'. Please check the link table value, that it has the value '4'.

Answer (score 1):

```
if((select count(*) from primaty_table where pk_id=4) > 0)
{
INSERT INTO `alias`( `alias`, `ref_links_id`) VALUES ("3334",4)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone will find this, my problem was that in my MySQL script I had Engine = MyISAM; instead of InnoDB. changed Engine = InnoDB; and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

`ref_links_id` 4 will be already exist in the table `alias`. You can not insert duplicate value for foreign key constraint.

If you want to delete foreign key,

```
ALTER TABLE `alias` DROP FOREIGN KEY ref_links_id;
```

Then try `INSERT INTO`alias`(`alias`,`ref_links_id`) VALUES ("3334",4)`